# How to replace multiple " in between two, with help of sed or awk

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

In csv file If in between two, there are more than two `"` present then I want to replace them with only two `"` using shell script.

**Example**

If in csv file it is like, `"""any word""`, it should get replaced with, `"any word"`, or if it is like, `[any number of "]`, it should get replaced with, `""`.

FYI: " this is double quote not two single quote.
and [] are not present actually in data , i gave it for understanding

Comment: why this `,[any number of "],` should be replaced with `,"",` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it is a requirement for loading data in database
as in if there are more than two " present between two , it creates a problem

Comment: how this value `,[any "word" sentence],` should be treated?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest there may be any normal English word in between two ,
example :  ,"general_id"", should get replaced by ,"general_id",

Comment: Are you trying to be robust against SQL-injection? If yes you should study the concept of bound values/parameters.

Comment: @Yunnosch no nothing complicated like that
just normal string replacement

Comment: I can't believe you've got answers to this! Please [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output that covers all of your possible uses cases, especially the ones you think will be hard to deal with such as if you can have commas and/or newlines in the middle of quoted fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

sample `testfile` contents:

```
sdsdf,"""hello"",sdsdf
asdasd,[asdasd asdasd]",sdfsdf
sdf,"[asdasd]",asdasd
```

---

The job:

```
awk -F, '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/"{2,}/) gsub(/"+/,"\"",$i); 
           else if($i~/^[^"]*"{1,}[^"]*$/) $i="\"\""; }1' OFS=',' testfile
```

The output:

```
sdsdf,"hello",sdsdf
asdasd,"",sdfsdf
sdf,"[asdasd]",asdasd
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sed solution, which as OP works between commas, but which doesn't work, if there are commas in between the quotation marks:

`sed ':a;s/\(,"[^,"]*\|^"[^,"]*\)"\([^,]\)/\1\2/;ta' testfile`

Using Roman's test file my output is:

```
sdsdf,"hello",sdsdf
asdasd,[asdasd asdasd]",sdfsdf
sdf,"[asdasd]",asdasd
```

Note that the second field of the second line is different in my version, as I'm not sure what behavior OP wants in that case or if fields like that even exist.

Comment: sed ':a;s/\(,"[^,"]*\)"\([^,]\)/\1\2/;ta' testfile 
this is working for me
can you just explain how it works please

Comment: it is removing the excess " correctly but it is also removing the " which are at the end of the line :(

Comment: It works by applying the substitution which using modern regex would be written as `s/(,"[^,"]*|^"[^,"]*)"([^,])/\1\2/` and then running the substitution again if there was a match. The substitution (which I've updated to correct a bug when matching the first field) removes quotation marks within fields. You can use www.regex101.com to learn about how regular expressions work. Update your question with a test file. My version doesn't removing quotation marks at end of line in `foo,""`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Roman's file

```
awk -F, '{gsub(/"""hello""/,"\42hello\42",$2)gsub(/\[asdasd asdasd\]/,"\42")}1' OFS=, file

sdsdf,"hello",sdsdf
asdasd,"",sdfsdf
sdf,"[asdasd]",asdasd
```